# How to append HTML of a page to iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, frontend

Now I have html codes of a page from back end like this.

[image]

So I wanna know how to append these to iframe using jquery or javascript.

```
<iframe id="t-frame" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it:

```
$("#t-frame").attr("src","link website");
```

Comment: technically, you need quotes around the id, like `$("#t-frame")`

Comment: sorry,but I only have html codes ,not a website url

Comment: i did like this,and it works :-)))))))
var iframe0=$("#t-frame").contents().find("html");
iframe0.empty().append(data.html);

Comment: coppy source html  add in to body.html (code html).

$(function() {
 var $frame = $('<iframe style="width:200px; height:100px;">');
 $('body').html( $frame );
 setTimeout( function() {
  var doc = $frame[0].contentWindow.document;
  var $body = $('body',doc);
  $body.html('<h1>Test</h1>');
 }, 1 );
});